# Web API sometime working some time failed in Windows Azure "NetworkError": 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, azure-sql-database, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-interception

We Have Deployed our first application on Windows azure with Windows SQL Azure Database. In my application we facing sometime to execute Web services to complete implementation.

We Configured all required setting and web site working properly but some time User Registration failed sometime not with same valid input. Please help me I am in new in Windows Azure.
See Error and Success

- Error Image Link http://tourneypick.com/Upload/2015-09-10%2017_46_06-Firebug%20-%20register%20_%20Application.png
- Success on Next click Image Link  http://tourneypick.com/Upload/2015_09_10_17_45_27_Firebug_register_Application.png

This working on staging server properly.

Comment: Its Argent please help me

Comment: without seeing your code it is hard to help you with a 500 error

Comment: Click on the response tab and take a screenshot of that, then we can see what is being rendered as the response.  That might reveal what the error is that is occurring.

Comment: Thank for your response! "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{a6f7204e-c463-49a4-867e-4fcda1574edd} Line Number 1, Column 1:"  I i connect to mssql2014 from our server this working fine from local but not from web site i think problem could be in configuration in  web config with Azure ... i m new in azure Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long effort I analyse that: My application was hosted in West US Region in Azure Cloud and database was in Central US region that's why system take too much time to load data. After change database region to West US means Application and database on same region. Now execution speed become fast and no 500 error.

- Issue might be connection time out